# using Silverlight in SCORM content

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, wss, scorm, slk

I'm building a LMS system using Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) with the Sharepoint Learning Kit (SLK).  One of the requirements is to be able to host Silverlight content within the SCORM package.  Has anyone done this before?  I haven't been able to find much (anything) online that talks about how to do this.  Most of the content tools that exist for SCORM are able to handle Flash, but I haven't come across anything that will do Silverlight.

If all else fails, I'll try to manually build a SCORM package, but I'd really like to find some examples or howtos of doing this with Silverlight first.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done it personally before, but from a SCORM perspective the content is a black box. It shouldn't matter if it is implemented in Flash, Silverlight, or whatever. The complex part about using plug-in technologies with SCORM is establishing communication with the SCORM API via JavaScript. In Flash, it can be tricky to communicate establish a communication link between the Flash movie and JavaScript in the browser. It looks like this is a [straightforward process in Silverlight](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx).

Comment: That's what I've been thinking, I was just hoping someone had already been down this road and had written about it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SCORM CLOUD, and then build an API to talk to it.  http://www.scorm.com/

Hope this helps,
Dan Linstedt
http://danLinstedt.com